Do Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ generalize to solid angles?
Is there a known generalization of Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ for solid angles or higher-dimensional angles?
If not, how might one go about establishing such a generalization?
Maybe the surface of the cone enclosing the solid angle is projected as areas on the 3 coordinate planes XY, YZ and ZX?

@Masd No. Quaternions do not use solid angles.

Euler's formula is about rotations. Solid angles aren't related to rotations, so I doubt there's really any sort of Euler's formula.

@YvesDaoust It is highly geometric. It is the map of an "infinitesimal rotation" $i$ "sustained" for an amount of time $\theta$ to the corresponding rotation. It's also possible to identify $i$ with the plane of rotation itself. This idea generalizes to arbitrary dimensions, and generalizing it to 3 dimensions is how you get the quaternions.

@Nicholas Todoroff The formula also projects/decomposes a vector into real and imaginary axis.

The projections you mention in your question highly depend on which cone you choose. The angle in Euler's formula isn't acting as a piece of arc length, it's acting as a position on the unit circle. Solid angle does not have enough information to determine a specific cone for you to project.

@Nicholas Todoroff In Clifford algebra, which generalizes complex numbers, elements like bivectors represent a quantity of area, and not an area with a specified shape. Euler formula generalizes to bivectors, so maybe the solid angle can be taken as a quantity without shape, or with a standard shape.

The bivector exponential in 3D Euclidean space is the quaternion exponential, but you didn't seem interested in that. In general the bivector exponential is mapping from planes to rotations, and again I don't see how solid angles have anything to do with rotations. You could define a "solid angle bivector" by summing over all infinitesimal solid angles multiplied by the unit bivector orthogonal to the position vector, but I don't see what that quantity does for you and I don't see how its exponential would have any real significance.

@Nicholas Todoroff what I meant is that maybe the solid angle should be taken as a shapeless quantity, (the reference to bivector is just illustrative of shapeless objects).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@YvesDaoust "has no particular geometric interpretation (for the LHS)" is what you said. That statement is false, "highly" or not. Why does it matter if it "tells us anything new"? I have no idea what sort of "new" information you're looking for. And the presence of a limit does not "negate" the presence of any geometry, so I don't see how that matters.

When you say solid, you mean 3D? Also note that the angle is a result of describing a 2d complex number not an angle. Describing a 2D angle as a COMPLEX number will require 4D and solid will require 6D. The mentioning of Quaternions extends the solid angle into a single complex domain, if it has COMPLEX value/use.

@Moti. I linked to the wikipedia page of solid angles

How you see the practical use of such extension into the complex realm?

@Moti I'm looking for a formula independent of the dimension (for any dimension), to find how it applies to fractional dimension.

@Nicholas Todoroff Euler's formula is not "about rotations." Rather, it describes a transformation between polar and rectangular coordinates. Rotations can be achieved by multiplying either side of the formula by an external element, but this multiplication is not inherent to the formula itself. To draw an analogy, claiming that Euler's formula is about rotations because it is easier to understand in polar coordinates is akin to asserting that it is about vector addition simply because vector addition is better understood using rectangular coordinates.

Sorry, but your last sentence is honestly incomprehensible to me. I don't understand what your trying to say. "This multiplication is not inherent to the formula..." It is, it's $e^{\theta i}=e^{\theta i}\cdot 1$. And if you're trying to tell me that polar coordinates don't have anything to do with rotations... I really don't know how to respond to that.

@Nicholas Todoroff I said that polar coordinates help to understand rotations, but you cannot do  a rotation without a product, and the product is outside of Euler's formula. Is a different operation, same as an addition is a different operation, It's pointless to argue $e^{i \theta}=0+e^{i \theta}$. Your argument is akin to claiming that euler formula is about polynomials, just because you can use complex numbers on polynomials.

I think, you should look up spherical trigonometry. There, solid angle is the surface of a spherical triangle.

Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ works in all cases, regardless of what you consider $\theta$ to be: angle, solid algle, length or whatever. It is just a relation between functions.

Note that the generalization of the Euler's formula to the higher-dimensional hypercomplex numbers does not involve solid angle.
